# route traffic on certain port through certain interface?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn, route

I am currently running a system in which I need to be able to send and recieve  HTTP and HTTPS traffic directly, however all other traffic must go via a VPN.

My setup is :

x2 interfaces : eth0 (local network, behind a router) and tun0 (openvpn client)

Currently all traffic is routed through my vpn, i was wondering if it were possible to **not** route http and https traffic (80, 443) through the VPN.

Here is the routing table when the system and openvpn client have started :

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.13.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
10.8.13.1 via 10.8.13.5 dev tun0 
10.8.13.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.13.6 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.13.5 dev tun0 
176.67.168.144 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.56 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

I have read through other similar questions however either the answers don't reroute the traffic or just block it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing is at IP layer 3. TCP is at layer 4, so routing alone isn't enough to deal with this.

In short: the interesting traffic has to be [tagged with `iptables`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#MARK), and tagged packets selected with [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip-rule.8.en.html)'s `fwmark` to use a separate routing table. Then two more fixes have to be applied for the locally initiated/receiving traffic case, which is more difficult than the routed case. All the settings are of course done on the local system.

Routing table `80` (a matching symbolic name can be added in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` but that's not mandatory) and mark `0x80` were "arbitrarily" chosen.

```
ip route add table 80 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link src 192.168.1.56
ip route add table 80 default dev eth0 via 192.168.1.1
```

Using `-I` to ensure that the iptables rules aren't appended too late. You should check with your current rules how to reorder that if needed:

```
iptables -t mangle -N markports
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT 1 -m mark --mark 0 -j markports
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT 2 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t mangle -A markports -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x80
iptables -t mangle -A markports -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 0x80

ip rule add fwmark 0x80 lookup 80
```

This blog: [Netfilter Connmark » To Linux and beyond !](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/) gives good informations on `CONNMARK`.

This should have been working, but actually the wrong default outgoing IP will have been selected at the first routing decision, because the route was about to be through `tun0`. At the reroute check made because of the `mangle/OUTPUT`'s mark (see this [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) for clarification), this IP won't change. If the traffic handled was routed instead of being locally initiated, this problem wouldn't happen (using a separate net namespace to ensure this is a solution for services, probably not for a Desktop). So this requires also a layer of `MASQUERADE` (or `SNAT` for more complex cases) on top of it:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -m mark --mark 0x80 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now that the outgoing source IP is correct, it's still not working: the [reverse path filter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.14.56#n1124) triggers in the return path for about the same reason: the routing decision made before `PREROUTING` doesn't know the `fwmark` for now (despite the [previous schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) placing `mangle/PREROUTING` before the routing decision, that's apparently not the case), thus considers the return traffic packets to be spoofed and drops them early. The `eth0` interface's [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.14.56#n1124) has to be put in loose mode for this to be allowed. This might have some (very minor behind NAT) security issues but I found it unavoidable for this non-routed case:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
```

You'll have to find how to set it permanently (eg `echo net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=2 > /etc/sysctl.d/90-local-loose-mode.conf` if nothing else alters it later).

Tested ok using namespaces with similar settings to OP's.

NOTE: DNS requests will still go through the tunnel. Some geolocalized web services might not work as expected.

Comment: newer kernels ( >= 4.17) can have ip rules with tcp or udp selectors (policy routing has now a leg in layer 4). So this could be done without any use of iptables now, but I'm not sure that would give a better result (except maybe with regard to MTU/MSS)

Comment: This is an amazing post, thank you very much! Can maybe add an explanation what the `--restore-mark` and `--save-mark` commands are?

Comment: @Benibr conntrack provides an in-kernel-memory lookup database of tracked flows. A packet is associated to a flow entry there. One can choose to store a packet's mark which exists only ephemerally (packet's lifespan) in this "database" to be memorized over time (a flow could last days) and retrieved later to be set on a new packet  of the same flow to get same outcome. For details see the link in my answer: [Netfilter Connmark » To Linux and beyond !](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/), or the man page: https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#CONNMARK .