# Ping same server with different interfaces using different ports

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ping, route, iproute

In my SoC imx6 I have two 4G modems using two different operators. I would like to give a score to each one so I can detect the best interface for my critical application.

I decide to use a small application that can make a ping to a server via a specific port:

```
$ ./tcpclienttimeout --host google.com --port 80
hotsname:google.com:80 timeout:10s
socket google.com:80 connected. It took 23 milliseconds
23
```

I would like to target the same server but with two different ports (let's say port 5000 and 5001) to get the latency for each modem.

here is a schematic that describes what I need:

[image: here is a schematic that describes what I need:]

I was thinking to use `ip route add` but we can specify just the servers and interfaces, not the port.
Now I think that the solution will be using `iptables` (wich I don't understand at all)

thank you for your help.

Comment: iptables doesn't route, the routing stack does. So even if in some use cases you need iptables to complement the routing stack, you will *always* need ip route & co (ip rule etc.). You have to familiarize with multi-homing and its challenges. One old doc still mostly relevant: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: See also this answer of mine: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581419/routing-port-traffic-over-specific-interface/582464#582464

Comment: You can use [Linux Policy Routing](https://www.system-rescue.org/networking/Destination-port-routing/)